# Flutter Failed to ensure /storage/F2B8-9797/Android/data/ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to prepare /storage in Real Device

Tags: java, android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, android-download-manager

I am a beginner. I am trying to create a Dashboard app, in which I need to download certain file using URL. So I have used 'flutter_downloader' package. I can able to download the file in emulator but not on actual device.

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER" />
   <application
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:label="report_dashboard_app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

My Full Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:report_dashboard_app/main.dart';
import 'package:report_dashboard_app/route_generator.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterDownloader.initialize(
      debug: true // optional: set false to disable printing logs to console
      );

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: DUOthersDashboard(),
    // initialRoute: '/duOthersdashboard',
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
  ));
}

class DUOthersDashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class Choice {
  Choice(
      {this.viewUrl,
      this.downloadUrl,
      this.title,
      this.colors,
      this.ext,
      // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
      this.operatorId,
      this.navRoute});

  String title;

  String colors;
  String navRoute;
  String viewUrl;
  String downloadUrl;
  String ext;
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  String operatorId;
  factory Choice.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedData) {
    return Choice(
      title: parsedData['operator_name'].toString(),
      operatorId: parsedData['operator_id'].toString(),
      colors: parsedData['color'].toString(),
      navRoute: '/duOthersWebView',
      viewUrl: parsedData['viewUrl'].toString(),
      downloadUrl: parsedData['downloadUrl'].toString(),
      ext: parsedData['downloadUrlExt'].toString(),
    );
  }
}

Future<List<Choice>> fetchSeasons() async {
  final response = await http.get(
      "https://reports.symbioticinfo.com/gateway/action?application=du_reports&action=mobile_view_dashboard&mobile_user=Yes");

  print(response);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);

    print(list);
    var seasons = list.map((season) => Choice.fromJson(season)).toList();
    return seasons;
  } else {
    print('Error!!');
    throw Exception('Failed to Load Post');
  }
}

class _State extends State<DUOthersDashboard> {
  String reportDashboardUser = "";
  String reportDashboardUserID = "";
  String reportDashboardUserRoleid = "";
  String reportDashboardUserTeam = "";

  int progress = 0;

  ReceivePort _receivePort = ReceivePort();
  static downloadingCallback(id, status, progress) {
    ///Looking up for a send port
    SendPort sendPort = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName("downloading");

    ///ssending the data
    sendPort.send([id, status, progress]);
  }

  void logout() {
    removeValues();
  }

  removeValues() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //Remove String
    await prefs.remove('reportDashboardUser');
    await prefs.remove('reportDashboardUserID');
    await prefs.remove('reportDashboardUserRoleid');
    await prefs.remove('reportDashboardUserTeam');

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
      // the new route
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => MyApp(),
      ),

      // this function should return true when we're done removing routes
      // but because we want to remove all other screens, we make it
      // always return false
      (Route route) => false,
    );
  }

  Future<List<Choice>> choices;
  void initState() {
    IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
        _receivePort.sendPort, "downloading");
    _receivePort.listen((message) {
      setState(() {
        progress = message[2];
      });

      print(progress);
    });

    FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadingCallback);

    choices = fetchSeasons();
    super.initState();
  }

  checkUser() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      reportDashboardUser = prefs.getString('reportDashboardUser');
      reportDashboardUserID = prefs.getString('reportDashboardUserID');
      reportDashboardUserRoleid = prefs.getString('reportDashboardUserRoleid');
      reportDashboardUserTeam = prefs.getString('reportDashboardUserTeam');
    });

    if (reportDashboardUser == null ||
        reportDashboardUserID == null ||
        reportDashboardUserRoleid == null ||
        reportDashboardUserTeam == null) {
      Navigator.pop(context,
          new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DUOthersDashboard()));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text('DUOthers Dashboard'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent.shade400,
            elevation: 10,
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(IconData(0xe848, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')),
                  onPressed: () => logout()),
            ]),
        // body: FutureBuilder<List<Choice>>(
        //     future: choices,
        //     builder: (context, snapshot) {
        //       GridView.count(
        //           crossAxisCount: 2,
        //           crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        //           mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
        //           children: List.generate(snapshot.data.length, (index) {
        //             return Center(
        //               child: SelectCard(choice: snapshot.data[index]),
        //             );
        //           }));
        //     }));
        body: FutureBuilder<List<Choice>>(
          future: choices,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                    //  print(snapshot.data[index]);
                    return Center(
                      child: SelectCard(choice: snapshot.data[index]),
                    );
                  });
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              print(snapshot);
              return Text("Error");
            }
            return Text("Loading...");
          },
        ));
  }
}

colorChange(clr) {
  Color pickerColor = new Color(clr);

  Color newColor = new Color(pickerColor.value);

  return newColor;
}

Future<String> _findLocalPath() async {
  final externalDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

  
  return externalDirectory.path;
}

void download(downloadurl, fileName1, fileExt) async {
  final status = await Permission.storage.request();

  
  if (status.isGranted) {
    // final externalDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

    final _localPath =
        (await _findLocalPath()) + Platform.pathSeparator + 'Download';
    final savedDir = Directory(_localPath);
    bool hasExisted = await savedDir.exists();
    if (!hasExisted) {
      savedDir.create();
    }
print("$_localPath/$fileName1.$fileExt");
    await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
      url: downloadurl,
      savedDir:_localPath,
      fileName: "$fileName1.$fileExt",
      showNotification: true,
      openFileFromNotification: true,
    );
  } else {
    print("Permission Denied");
  }
}

class SelectCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const SelectCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);
  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.white);

    // print(choice.downloadUrl);
    final TextStyle paraStyle = TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.white);
    bool _viewVisible = false;
    bool _downVisible = false;
    if (choice.viewUrl != '-') {
      _viewVisible = !_viewVisible;
    }
    if (choice.downloadUrl != '-') {
      _downVisible = !_downVisible;
    }
    print(choice.downloadUrl);
    return Card(
        child: Container(
      // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1.0,
      // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1.0,
      color: new Color(int.parse(choice.colors)),
      child: InkWell(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                ),
                Container(
                    //  alignment:Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      choice.title,
                      style: textStyle,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: _viewVisible,
                      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          // padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
                          // padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 65, 0, 0),
                          // alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(choice.navRoute,
                                arguments: choice.viewUrl);
                          },

                          // padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),

                          child: new Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'View Report',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_forward,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )
                            ],
                          )),
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: _downVisible,
                      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        child: new Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'Download Report',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_circle_down_rounded,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          download(
                              choice.downloadUrl, choice.operatorId, choice.ext);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

My error image,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRN8X.png)

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong and how can I solve it?

Comment: No  we cant as we dont know where to look. You posted so much irrelevant code. Do you expect us to dig through that all? Clean up please. Only a few relevant lines will do.

Comment: Post errors as text too. No images.